# SQL Display but remove some rows

Tags: sql, select

I am a newbie in PHP, I have this tables in database:

```
`Table_one`  `Table_two`
id | name    id | name
1  | a       1  | a
2  | b       2  | b
3  | c       5  | e
4  | d
5  | e
6  | f
```

but i want the output like this :

```
`Table_one`
id | name    
3  | c    
4  | d
6  | f
```

Comment: I never knew anything about  ```NOT EXISTS```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the rows of `Table_one` which don't match exactly in both columns with any row of `Table_two` you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t1.* from Table_one t1
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from Table_two t2 
  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name
)
```

or with a `LEFT` join from which you will return only the non matching rows:

```
select t1.* 
from Table_one t1 left join Table_two t2
on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name
where t2.id is null
```